# PL/SQL Statements ignored & Not enough values

Tags: plsql, procedures

```
--Below is for testing only - to be deleted later
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE movie_rental_sp 
    (movieIdCount IN OUT NUMBER,
    movieID IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
noMovie EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(movie_id)
    INTO movieIdCount
    FROM MM_MOVIE
    WHERE MOVIE_ID = movieID;
IF movieIdCount = 0 THEN
RAISE noMovie;
END IF;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN noMovie THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No movies found');
END;
/
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE MOVIE_RENTAL_SP:

LINE/COL ERROR

---

7/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/2      PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT has 2 columns, but your INTO only 1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the select statement to,

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID, count(movie_id)
INTO movieID , movieIdCount
.....
```